# Weighted least square - fit a plane to 3D point set

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, linear-algebra, least-squares

I am fitting a plane to a 3D point set with the least square method. I already have algorithm to do that, but I want to modify it to use weighted least square. Meaning I have a weight for each point (the bigger weight, the closer the plane should be to the point).

The current algorithm (without weight) looks like this:

Compute the sum:

```
for(Point3D p3d : pointCloud) {
    pos = p3d.getPosition();
    fSumX += pos[0];
    fSumY += pos[1];
    fSumZ += pos[2];
    fSumXX += pos[0]*pos[0];
    fSumXY += pos[0]*pos[1];
    fSumXZ += pos[0]*pos[2];
    fSumYY += pos[1]*pos[1];
    fSumYZ += pos[1]*pos[2];
}
```

than make the matrices:

```
double[][] A = {
    {fSumXX, fSumXY, fSumX},
    {fSumXY, fSumYY, fSumY},
    {fSumX,  fSumY,  pointCloud.size()}
};

double[][] B =  {
    {fSumXZ},
    {fSumYZ},
    {fSumZ}
};
```

than solve Ax = B and the 3 components of the solution are the coefficients of the fitted plain...

So, can you please help me how to modify this to use weights? Thanks!

Comment: FYI -- if you can have lots of points (> say 20) and/or the coordinates have a large offset, don't ever compute statistics the way you are doing (by taking the sums of squares of the raw position) -- it has poor sensitivity to numerical errors. At a minimum, you can subtract off the mean value of the X/Y/Z coordinates first, then do your processing, then at the end add the offsets back. There are other algorithm-specific ways of doing this, but I don't understand exactly how your algorithm uses least squares so can't help more than that.

Comment: What do you mean by offset? (sorry, don't understand it in this context).

Comment: Quick example: points p1=(10001, 10002, 10003), p2=(10005, 10006, 10007), p3=(10009, 10004, 10008). These have mean values of (10005, 10004, 10006). So you offset (translate) the point coordinates by the opposite of this amount to get p1' = (-4, -2, -3), p2' = (0,2,1), p3' = (4,0,2). Then do your math, then add back in the offset.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Intuition**

A point `x` on a plane defined by normal `n` and a point on the plane `p` obeys: `n.(x - p) = 0`. If a point `y` does not lie on the plane, `n.(y -p)` will not be equal to zero, so a useful way to define a cost is by `|n.(y - p)|^2` . This is the squared distance of the point  `y` from the plane.

With equal weights, you want to find an `n` that minimizes the total squared error when summing over the points:

```
f(n) = sum_i | n.(x_i - p) |^2
```

Now this assumes we know *some* point `p` that lies on the plane. We can easily compute one as the centroid, which is simply the component-wise mean of the points in the point cloud and will always lie in the least-squares plane.

**Solution**

Let's define a matrix `M` where each row is the `ith` point `x_i` minus the centroid `c`, we can re-write:

```
f(n) = | M n |^2
```

You should be able to convince yourself that this matrix multiplication version is the same as the sum on the previous equation.

You can then take [singular value decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of `M`, and the `n` you want is then given by the right singular vector of `M` that corresponds to the smallest singular value.

To incorporate weights you simply need to define a weight `w_i` for each point. Calculate `c` as the weighted average of the points, and change `sum_i | n.(x_i - c) |^2` to `sum_i | w_i * n.(x_i - c) |^2`, and the matrix `M` in a similar way. Then solve as before.

Answer (score 3):

Multiply each term in each sum by the corresponding weight. For example:

```
fSumZ += weight * pos[2];
fSumXX += weight * pos[0]*pos[0];
```

Since `pointCloude.size()` is the sum of `1` for all points, it should be replaced with the sum of all weights.

Comment: I thought it should be enought to multiply each term by the weight, but I wasn't sure... I'll try it and get back. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Start from redefining the least-square error calculation. The formula tries to minimize the sum of squares of errors. Multiply the squared error by a function of two points which decreases with their distance. Then try to minimize the weighted sum of squared errors and derive the coefficients from that.