# Plane fitting to 4 (or more) XYZ points

Tags: python, geometry, least-squares, plane

I have 4 points, which are very near to be at the one plane - it is the 1,4-Dihydropyridine cycle.

I need to calculate distance from C3 and N1 to the plane, which is made of C1-C2-C4-C5.
Calculating distance is OK, but fitting plane is quite difficult to me.

1,4-DHP cycle:

[image: 1,4-DHP cycle]

1,4-DHP cycle, another view:

[image: 1,4-DHP cycle, another view]

```
from array import *
from numpy import *
from scipy import *

# coordinates (XYZ) of C1, C2, C4 and C5
x = [0.274791784, -1.001679346, -1.851320839, 0.365840754]
y = [-1.155674199, -1.215133985, 0.053119249, 1.162878076]
z = [1.216239624, 0.764265677, 0.956099579, 1.198231236]

# plane equation Ax + By + Cz = D
# non-fitted plane
abcd = [0.506645455682, -0.185724560275, -1.43998120646, 1.37626378129]

# creating distance variable
distance =  zeros(4, float)

# calculating distance from point to plane
for i in range(4):
    distance[i] = (x[i]*abcd[0]+y[i]*abcd[1]+z[i]*abcd[2]+abcd[3])/sqrt(abcd[0]**2 + abcd[1]**2 + abcd[2]**2)
    
print distance

# calculating squares
squares = distance**2

print squares
```

How to make sum(squares) minimized? I have tried least squares, but it is too hard for me.

Comment: Try asking on math.stackexchange?

You don't seem to need coding help atm :)

Comment: I'm not sure mentioning "1,4-Dihydropyridine cycle" helps in this case. Have you googled "plane fitting python" ? The fifth result looks promising...

Comment: I wrote a similar answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243645/weighted-least-square-fit-a-plane-to-3d-point-set/9243785#9243785) that may be useful (just ignore the very last part about weights)

Comment: The information linked by @MrE is crucial to understanding what my solution does behind the scenes. Otherwise you are simply dealing with a magic black box.

Comment: Yes! The most difficult is to understand how the distance is being calculated.

Comment: @user1071136 - You assume that your Google bubble is the same as the reader's Google bubble, plus that the bubbles remain static over time. Neither is true. A link is more helpful than a vague "You should google 'this' and click the nth result." Just to prove my point, currently the first result for such a search on DuckDuckGo is this very question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The fact that you are fitting to a plane is only slightly relevant here. What you are trying to do is minimize a *particular* function starting from a guess. For that use `scipy.optimize`. Note that there is no guarantee that this is the **globally optimal** solution, only **locally optimal**. A different initial condition may converge to a different result, this works well if you start close to the local minima you are seeking.

I've taken the liberty to clean up your code by taking advantage of numpy's broadcasting:

```
import numpy as np

# coordinates (XYZ) of C1, C2, C4 and C5
XYZ = np.array([
        [0.274791784, -1.001679346, -1.851320839, 0.365840754],
        [-1.155674199, -1.215133985, 0.053119249, 1.162878076],
        [1.216239624, 0.764265677, 0.956099579, 1.198231236]])

# Inital guess of the plane
p0 = [0.506645455682, -0.185724560275, -1.43998120646, 1.37626378129]

def f_min(X,p):
    plane_xyz = p[0:3]
    distance = (plane_xyz*X.T).sum(axis=1) + p[3]
    return distance / np.linalg.norm(plane_xyz)

def residuals(params, signal, X):
    return f_min(X, params)

from scipy.optimize import leastsq
sol = leastsq(residuals, p0, args=(None, XYZ))[0]

print("Solution: ", sol)
print("Old Error: ", (f_min(XYZ, p0)**2).sum())
print("New Error: ", (f_min(XYZ, sol)**2).sum())
```

This gives:

```
Solution:  [  14.74286241    5.84070802 -101.4155017   114.6745077 ]
Old Error:  0.441513295404
New Error:  0.0453564286112
```

Comment: This code would work unchanged even with more than 4 points...isn't it?
just adding coordinates to the first array....

Comment: @Hooked You say *locally optimal*, but is there a way to guarantee a globally optimal solution without respect to initial conditions?  I don't know enough linear algebra to say for myself

Comment: @frank in general the answer is no, for an arbitrary cost function there is no way to guarantee you are at the global minimum vs a local one. However, there is an important subset of (linear) problems where we can both guarantee and find the solution in polynomial time. This is in fact one of the major strengths of linear algebra. Many problems that are non-linear can be approximated to a linear one, so you can solve the approximate problem exactly FWIW.

Comment: should it not be absolute distance that should be minimized?

Comment: @NiranjanKotha it depends! The L1 and L2 norms (absolute vs mean squared) always give the same ranking, but are different measures of how far away you are from the goal. For iterative solvers this means they have the same minimum (thus the same "right" answers), but different gradients. A different gradient allows some solvers to get to the solution faster. In many cases, but not all, L2 norms converge faster.

Comment: @frank Scipy has a [method to find the global minimum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html).

Answer (score 22):

That sounds about right, but you should replace the nonlinear optimization with an SVD. The following creates the moment of inertia tensor, M, and then SVD's it to get the normal to the plane. This should be a close approximation to the least-squares fit and be much faster and more predictable. It returns the point-cloud center and the normal.

```
def planeFit(points):
    """
    p, n = planeFit(points)

    Given an array, points, of shape (d,...)
    representing points in d-dimensional space,
    fit an d-dimensional plane to the points.
    Return a point, p, on the plane (the point-cloud centroid),
    and the normal, n.
    """
    import numpy as np
    from numpy.linalg import svd
    points = np.reshape(points, (np.shape(points)[0], -1)) # Collapse trialing dimensions
    assert points.shape[0] <= points.shape[1], "There are only {} points in {} dimensions.".format(points.shape[1], points.shape[0])
    ctr = points.mean(axis=1)
    x = points - ctr[:,np.newaxis]
    M = np.dot(x, x.T) # Could also use np.cov(x) here.
    return ctr, svd(M)[0][:,-1]
```

For example: Construct a 2D cloud at (10, 100) that is thin in the x direction and 100 times bigger in the y direction:

```
>>> pts = np.diag((.1, 10)).dot(randn(2,1000)) + np.reshape((10, 100),(2,-1))
```

The fit plane is very nearly at (10, 100) with a normal very nearly along the x axis.

```
>>> planeFit(pts)

    (array([ 10.00382471,  99.48404676]),
     array([  9.99999881e-01,   4.88824145e-04]))
```

Comment: But the Hooked's answer is very precise; measurements are in angstroms (precision in hundredths is not needed), also I have not so many points - speed is OK. But this is looking very interesting solution.

Comment: Using `scipy.optimize.leastsq` is great, but (assuming I didn't add a bug), this is the Right Way to do total least squares. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares

Comment: Also: if you really want to solve the full nonlinear problem, using the SVD-based fit is a quick way to get a very good starting point.

Comment: Why would this be less precise? This is in fact more precise than the non-linear optimization.

Comment: I'm rusty on this now. What I was thinking was that total least squares is the sum of squared errors whereas the SVD solution will give you (I think) the sum of squared r*sin(theta). Of course, for small theta, r*sin(theta) is very close to the Euclidean error, but for large error, not so much.

Comment: This works, but I would love to read the theory about why this works. do you have a reference?

Comment: @Gulzar the Wikipedia Total least squares link above should cover it. Conceptually this is finding the shape of an ellipsoid that fits the n-dimensional Gaussian blob, finding the direction of the thinnest dimension of the ellipsoid, and using that direction as the plane normal.

Comment: Thanks for the code !
As a matter of information, if you need to get back to a plane equation , with point r (x,y...) found on the plane and normal vector n, a point is in the plane if : n⋅(r−b) = 0

Answer (score 15):

Least squares should fit a plane easily.  The equation for a plane is: ax + by + c = z.  So set up matrices like this with all your data:

```
    x_0   y_0   1  
A = x_1   y_1   1  
          ... 
    x_n   y_n   1
```

And

```
    a  
x = b  
    c
```

And

```
    z_0   
B = z_1   
    ...   
    z_n
```

In other words: Ax = B. Now solve for x which are your coefficients.  But since you have more than 3 points, the system is over-determined so you need to use the left pseudo inverse.  So the answer is:

```
a 
b = (A^T A)^-1 A^T B
c
```

And here is some simple Python code with an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

N_POINTS = 10
TARGET_X_SLOPE = 2
TARGET_y_SLOPE = 3
TARGET_OFFSET  = 5
EXTENTS = 5
NOISE = 5

# create random data
xs = [np.random.uniform(2*EXTENTS)-EXTENTS for i in range(N_POINTS)]
ys = [np.random.uniform(2*EXTENTS)-EXTENTS for i in range(N_POINTS)]
zs = []
for i in range(N_POINTS):
    zs.append(xs[i]*TARGET_X_SLOPE + \
              ys[i]*TARGET_y_SLOPE + \
              TARGET_OFFSET + np.random.normal(scale=NOISE))

# plot raw data
plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, color='b')

# do fit
tmp_A = []
tmp_b = []
for i in range(len(xs)):
    tmp_A.append([xs[i], ys[i], 1])
    tmp_b.append(zs[i])
b = np.matrix(tmp_b).T
A = np.matrix(tmp_A)
fit = (A.T * A).I * A.T * b
errors = b - A * fit
residual = np.linalg.norm(errors)

print("solution: %f x + %f y + %f = z" % (fit[0], fit[1], fit[2]))
print("errors:")
print(errors)
print("residual: {}".format(residual))

# plot plane
xlim = ax.get_xlim()
ylim = ax.get_ylim()
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(xlim[0], xlim[1]),
                  np.arange(ylim[0], ylim[1]))
Z = np.zeros(X.shape)
for r in range(X.shape[0]):
    for c in range(X.shape[1]):
        Z[r,c] = fit[0] * X[r,c] + fit[1] * Y[r,c] + fit[2]
ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z, color='k')

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
plt.show()
```

The solution for your points:

```
0.143509 x + 0.057196 y + 1.129595 = z
```

[image: plane fit]

Comment: thank you for your answer. When I asked this question I had no idea how def function is working. And I couldn't find anything already working to use it for my task.

Comment: @Ben wait, maybe I didn't look at this code long enough, but this solution isn't iterative, right?  Again, just a first impression, but that doesn't sound very "machine learning," for lack of a better way to put it.  Does that mean this solution just takes the first guess as gospel?

Comment: This method is not robust to singular matrices.  Going to try others

Comment: @frank This solution is not iterative, and it is not machine learning.  It is just [ordinary least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) which is just straight forward math which minimizes the error of a model.  No, this won't work with singular matrices, and I am not sure what will.  I think that means there is something fundamentally wrong in the formulation of the problem.

Comment: This doesn't work in Python3 / new numpy. Would appreciate an edit, as I can't do it myself.

Comment: @Gulzar, It was just the print() function that needed to be updated for python3.  should work now.

Comment: This only works for points if they are defined as a function f(x, y) = z. If the points are more general (e.g. all in the xz-plane), this method breaks down. Use one of the great solutions below.

Answer (score 4):

This returns the 3D plane coefficients along with the RMSE of the fit.

The plane is provided in a homogeneous coordinate representation, meaning its dot product with the homogeneous coordinates of a point produces the distance between the two.

```py
def fit_plane(points):
    assert points.shape[1] == 3
    centroid = points.mean(axis=0)
    x = points - centroid[None, :]
    U, S, Vt = np.linalg.svd(x.T @ x)
    normal = U[:, -1]
    origin_distance = normal @ centroid
    rmse = np.sqrt(S[-1] / len(points))
    return np.hstack([normal, -origin_distance]), rmse
```

Minor note: the SVD can also be directly applied to the points instead of the outer product matrix, but I found it to be slower with NumPy's SVD implementation.

```py
U, S, Vt = np.linalg.svd(x.T, full_matrices=False)
rmse = S[-1] / np.sqrt(len(points))
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way aside from svd to quickly reach a solution while dealing with outliers ( when you have a large data set ) is ransac :

```
def fit_plane(voxels, iterations=50, inlier_thresh=10):  # voxels : x,y,z
    inliers, planes = [], []
    xy1 = np.concatenate([voxels[:, :-1], np.ones((voxels.shape[0], 1))], axis=1)
    z = voxels[:, -1].reshape(-1, 1)
    for _ in range(iterations):
        random_pts = voxels[np.random.choice(voxels.shape[0], voxels.shape[1] * 10, replace=False), :]
        plane_transformation, residual = fit_pts_to_plane(random_pts)
        inliers.append(((z - np.matmul(xy1, plane_transformation)) <= inlier_thresh).sum())
        planes.append(plane_transformation)
    return planes[np.array(inliers).argmax()]


def fit_pts_to_plane(voxels):  # x y z  (m x 3)
    # https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99299/best-fitting-plane-given-a-set-of-points
    xy1 = np.concatenate([voxels[:, :-1], np.ones((voxels.shape[0], 1))], axis=1)
    z = voxels[:, -1].reshape(-1, 1)
    fit = np.matmul(np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(np.matmul(xy1.T, xy1)), xy1.T), z)
    errors = z - np.matmul(xy1, fit)
    residual = np.linalg.norm(errors)
    return fit, residual
```

Comment: voxels should give very close result, but it looks like require much more coding!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but voxels are equivalent to XYZ in the original question - you don't need to preprocess them in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. If your points are P[1]..P[n] then compute the mean M of these and subtract it from each, getting points p[1]..p[n]. Then compute C = Sum{ p[i]*p[i]'} (the "covariance" matrix of the points). Next diagonalise C, that is find orthogonal U and diagonal E so that C = U*E*U'. If your points are indeed on a plane then one of the eigenvalues (ie the diagonal entries of E) will be very small (with perfect arithmetic it would be 0). In any case if the j'th one of these is the smallest, then let the j'th column of U be (A,B,C) and compute D = -M'*N. These parameters define the "best" plane, the one such that the sum of the squares of the distances from the P[] to the plane is least.

Comment: It is very fast way, but I need exactly least-squares method.